# Return a way to set a property of a class

Tags: python, class, setter

So I have the following function:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = False

def test():
    test = Test()
    # And now return some way to set the test.test property
```

So I would like the `test` function to return some way to set test.test

I tried the following things:

```
def test():
    test = Test()
    return test.test

property = test()
property = True
# Doesn't work, doesn't pass a reference
```

Or what could work (but )

```
def test():
    test = Test()
    def set(to):
        test.test = to
    return set

fnc = test()
# But how do i execute it then
```

Of course, it would also be possible to just return the "test" object, but I don't want that because then the other properties of the Test object can then also be changed

Comment: I have hard time understanding what you want to achieve. But why not simply do ``test.test = True``?

Comment: Short answer: You can't make `a = b` do anything other than bind the name `a` to reference `b`.

Comment: I cant just return test because i dont want all the other fields of Test to be accessible

Comment: What is going to hold the reference to the instance of `Test` once the function `test` returns?

Comment: Use the second way, just *call the function*, `fnc(True)`

Comment: But there's no way to *see* the `Test` instance, since the only reference to it lives inside `fnc`, where it is inaccessible. There's no point in setting it if you can never access it.

Comment: _other properties of the Test object can then also be changed_ - If you want true hidden class attributes, I dont think you should be using Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = False

def test():
    test = Test()
    def set_test(val: bool):
        test.test = val
    return set_test

test()(True)  # test.test is now True... somewhere!
```

Note that a problem with this is that while you have a function that lets you change `test.test`, you don't actually have access to the `test` object to see whether it worked.

If you want to make the `test.test` value accessible without making the enclosing `test` object accessible, you could return a getter as well as a setter:

```
from typing import Callable, Tuple


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = False


def test() -> Tuple[Callable[[], bool], Callable[[bool], None]]:
    test = Test()

    def get_test() -> bool:
        return test.test

    def set_test(val: bool) -> None:
        test.test = val

    return get_test, set_test


get_test, set_test = test()
print(get_test())  # False
set_test(True)
print(get_test())  # True
```

Comment: This is what the OP already has. You could add how you can call `set_test`, which they seem to be missing, but as you point out, this isn't really useful.

Comment: Yes i didn't know how to call it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
class Test:
   def __init__(self):
       self.test = False

   def change_test_value(self,value):
        self.test=value

def test():
   test = Test()
   test.change_test_value(True)
```

Comment: Defining a setter method doesn't seem to be what is being asked. Question asked to return a function object